# change img src when hover parent element not working in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this code and i want to when hover mouse parent (Li) tag, change src img child tag...
this code in chrome correct but in firefox & ie not working

```
<li class="player">
 .
 .
 //some code.......
 .
 .
  <table>
    <tr class="tr-msg">
      <td>
         <a>
            <img class="msg" src="../images/message-icon-h.png" />
         </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</li>

 <style>
   .player:hover .msg{
     content:url("../images/message-icon.png");
    }
 </style>
```

Comment: Yep, question and code don't match at all!

Comment: `.player:hover .msg{...`

Comment: you looking for answer in css or jquery

Comment: each (css or jquery)...

Answer (score 2):

You called the class `.liplay` which doesn't exist in your HTML code. Change it to `.player` and it will work.

```
.player:hover .msg{
     content:url("../images/message-icon.png");
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mTqyN/)**

**EDIT:**

I recommend using `background-image` property to achieve what you want. You could change your CSS to this:

```
.player a{
    display:block;
    background-image: url("../images/message-icon-h.png");
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    }

.player:hover > a{
    display:block;
    background-image: url("../images/message-icon.png");
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
}
```

Another **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTqyN/2/)**

It's working in Chrome, FF, IE, Opera and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make that :

```
<style>

li.player:hover .msg
{
content:url("../images/message-icon.png");
}

</style>
```